# Tab bar controller adds child view controller in its viewControllers array on rotation

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

Due to some reason, I need to add a view controller as a child of my tab bar controller. Everything works fine until I rotate the device. On rotation, my child view controller is appended to the viewControllers array of tabBarController. Eventually, number of tab bar items are incremented by one.

I don't want it to be added to viewControllers array. Here's the code

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    addChildVC()
}

func addChildVC() {
    let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ChildVC") as! ChildVC
    self.tabBarController!.add(vc, frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 150, width: 200, height: 100))   //Any random frame
}}

extension UIViewController {
func add(_ child: UIViewController, frame: CGRect? = nil)
{
    addChild(child)

    if let frame = frame {
        child.view.frame = frame
    }

    view.addSubview(child.view)
    child.didMove(toParent: self)
}}
```

This is how my storyboard looks
[image: View controller embedded in navigation controller, embedded in tab bar controller.]

Here's a Gif to show what is actually happening (please look at the tab bar, it will shift its position because a new controller will be added on rotation)

[image]

Please let me know if there's any way to fix this.

Comment: `UITabBarController` overrides `addChild` and manages tabs as child controllers [https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbarcontroller]. 
If you want custom behaviour, you might need override your tab bar controller classs, override `addChild(_:)` method and determine the way how to add it: either custom way or via `super`. But it is a bad idea. If you need some custom behaviour, better add this child to current tab controller or add this tab bar controller to parent and then add new child to this shared parent with tab bar controller.

Comment: @ModoLtunzher Just out of curiosity; where in the documentation does it say that this method is overridden? BTW, the link you provided is broken on click, please remove brackets around it. Anyway, I agree with proposed solutions. But there are issues in at least tab bar controller and navigation controller when adding children to it. From my understanding this is an iOS bug or rather a misusage of framework (by itself ironically).

Comment: Link cntains odd `]` in th end, it leads to official docs.
’A container view controller that manages a radio-style selection interface, where the selection determines which **child** view controller to display. ’
`child view controllers` - make sure to consider docs wordings to touch child vcs routines